# Jquery validate with one input file multiple

Tags: jquery, file, validation, input, multiple-file-upload

I have one `<input type="file" id="file" name="file[] multiple>` and the jQuery doesn't work (of course it's not a commented line). There is no error messages in the Firefox dev tool. This is the jQuery validate code I'm using

```
$("#form_bug").validate({
  rules: {
    file: {
      accept: "image/*",
    },
  },
  messages: {
    file: {
      accept: "<?php echo $lang['err_file'] ?>"
    },
  },
});
```

I expect to have an error message and for jQuery to block submitting the form when one of the selected files in the input is not an image.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't any problem with my html, i just baddly copy it

I try your thinks and it doesn't work because the html id was 'file' and the jquery one was 'file[]', so i changed the html one and it works !
The thinks that was missing was the quote in jquery for "file[]", it was giving me an error before

Thanx for the tip.